# Deep linking is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am implementing deep linking inside our custom power apps. where inside the App >> OnStart, we define to read the Id parameter, as follow:-
[image]

then on the Form >> we define the parameter  as the Item for the form, as follow:-

[image]

but on the field when we try to get the value of a text field (or any other data type), using the Default property as follow:-

[image]

nothing will be shown.. so can anyone advice ?

Also i tried to add a test label >> and set its Text property to be equal to ThisItem.'Office / Cubicle #' .. i will get the value of the related field inside the variable.. so is the issue with the Default property?

Comment: As a troubleshooting step, does it work if you put the OnStart formula into a button and reference a text input? eg Set(varParamId,TextInput1.Text). I've used your formulas with a button and it works fine, so your logic is sound. Depending on your results, it may point you in a direction to investigate.

Comment: @user79408 the issue was that the form was in new mode,,, so need to change the form to be in view mode .. so it reads the value fr0m the default property..